# Crear e Insertar Qr en base de datos Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, zxing

Buen dia estoy ayudando en el desarrollo de un programa que genere QR automaticamente desgradaciadamente el programa lo estan haciendo un forms y reports de ORACLE version 6i, la cual no tiene plugin para crear QR asi que me ayuda en el proyecto es encontrar una manera de hacerlo, creo que lo consegui a medias, encontre un programa que crea Qrs en JAVA, ZXING
crea la imagen con el texto que uno quiera, pero yo quiero insertarla en una columna de la base de datos para que las demas personas que usan el otro desarrollo puedan tener acceso a ella, **lo que quiero lograr esque no genera la imagen si no esta pueda ser insertada de una vez a la base de datos**

````
    // Function to create the QR code
    
    
public static int escribir(String nombre, String rutaArchivo) {
        InputStream entrada = null;

        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        int ingresados = 0;
        try {
            File archivo;
            String insert;

 Conexion c = new Conexion();
         Connection con = c.getConexion();
            con.setAutoCommit(false);

            insert = "UPDATE puerto.recepcion_web\n"
                + "   SET COLUMN1 = ?\n"
                + "   WHERE rw_id_recepcion = 13462";

            pst = con.prepareStatement(insert);

            archivo = new File(rutaArchivo);

            entrada = new FileInputStream(archivo);

            
            pst.setBinaryStream(1, entrada, (int) archivo.length());

            ingresados = pst.executeUpdate();
            con.commit();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Mavenproject1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Mavenproject1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        } finally {
            try {
                if (entrada != null) {
                    entrada.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Mavenproject1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            try {
                if (pst != null) {
                    pst.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Mavenproject1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
        return ingresados;
    }

    public static void createQR(String data, String path,
            String charset, Map hashMap,
            int height, int width)
            throws WriterException, IOException {

        BitMatrix matrix = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(
                new String(data.getBytes(charset), charset),
                BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height);

        MatrixToImageWriter.writeToFile(
                matrix,
                path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('.') + 1),
                new File(path));
//        System.out.println(new File(path));
//        System.out.println(matrix);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws WriterException, IOException {
        // The data that the QR code will contain
        String data = "13462";

        // The path where the image will get saved
        String path = "img/13462.jpg";
        
        String archivo = "13462.jpg";

        // Encoding charset
        String charset = "UTF-8";

        Map<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel> hashMap
                = new HashMap<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel>();

        hashMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION,
                ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);

        // Create the QR code and save
        // in the specified folder
        // as a jpg file
        createQR(data, path, charset, hashMap, 200, 200);
        System.out.println("QR Code Generated!!! ");
    int escribir = escribir(archivo, path);
    } ```
````

Comment: ¿No sería mucho más fácil guardar en un campo de la base de datos el texto que está codificado en el QR y sólo generar el QR en la vista? Ya sea en Java o Javascript (si es una aplicación web), recibir una cadena de caracteres y crear la imagen es trivial, ahorrando mucho espacio en la base de datos. Al fin y al cabo un QR es una forma de **visualizar** datos, no deberíamos considerarlo **un dato** por sí mismo

Comment: Hola claro seria mucho mas facil, el problema esque en el lugar donde estoy usan de reportes REPORT 6i de ORACLE, el programa no tienen plugin para poder crear un QR y no hay mucha info en internet sobre ello

Answer (score 0):

Para insertar una imagen en la base de datos Oracle, tienes que seguir los siguientes pasos:

1: Crear un campo de tipo BLOB, por ejemplo:

```
NOMBRE VARCHAR2(128)
QR BLOB
```

El tipo BLOB en Oracle se utiliza para guardar todo tipo de archivos de gran tamaño hasta el orden de los GB.

2. En java espesificas que insertara un BLOB en el PrepareStament:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TABLA VALUES(?, ?)");

InputStream inImg = new FileInputStream("ruta\QR.jpg");

pstmt.setBlob(1, "QR.jpg");
pstmt.setBlob(2, inImg );
pstmt.execute();
```

3. Para obtener la imagen, ahora en el ResultSet le dices que el tipo de datos que recibirás es BLOB:

```
 Blob blobQR = rs.getBlob("QR");
```

En este punto lo que obtienes es el binario de lo que sea que guardaste en el campo utilizando `blobQR.getBinaryStream();` que retorna un `InputStream`, como desconozco los mecanismos que tiene Oracle Forms 6i para mostrar imágenes solo puedo darte una idea general de como seguir, como veo que en el código ya manejas FileInputStream si ya sabes como mostrar eso en Oracle Forms seria lo mismo para el InputStream que obtienes al llamar el método getBinaryStream.